# Magento add email to billing and shipping address

Tags: email, magento

I would like to add email adress of my clients to billing and shipping address.

To do that, I have tried to add `var order.getCustomerEmail()`, `var email` into html address template. But it doesn't fill it in.

Code example:

```
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}<br/>
{{depend company}}{{var company}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}<br />{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if city}}{{var city}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}<br/>
{{var country}}<br/>
{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}
{{depend fax}}<br/>F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
**<br/>Email: {{var order.getCustomerEmail()}}**
{{depend vat_id}}<br/>VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}
```

Can it be because of `not registered users`? But they are also required to enter an email address.

Comment: do you want it on sales order email?

Comment: Yes I would like to add customers email to 'sales order email'

Answer (score 0):

If you want the customer's email in sales order email, change the below file

`\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order.php`
 locate the function `sendNewOrderEmail()`

```
$email =$order->getCustomerEmail();
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
       'order'        => $this,
       'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
       'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml,
       'email'       => $email
     )
);
```

Now you can access this variable like

```
{{var email}}
```

**NOTE** I will advice not to make changes in the core file